# Regarding 3D plot of a surface

Tags: plotting

I can plot a surface using ContourPlot3D for some range of x,y,z like shown below.

```
ContourPlot3D[ -(x^2/2) + 16.7 z == 0, {x, -40, 40}, {y, -40, 
      40}, {z, -40, 40}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Small, 
     ContourStyle -> 
      Directive[SkyBlue, Opacity[0.4], Specularity[White, 30]], 
     BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None,
       2 -> None, {1, _} -> Directive[Thick, Red]}]
```

and getting proper parabola surface for ranges (x, -40, 40), (y, -40,
40), (z, -40, 40).
But I do not know how to plot the same quadratic  surface $f = -(x^2/2) + 16.7 z $   for a given set of data.
Suppose, the data set is

```
data={10., 10., 10.}, {-5.56506, -0.826194, 29.6758}, {-0.52783,-0.676796, 14.6942}, {8.3787, 12.6581, 19.9009}, {5.88768, 0.866465, 30.2086}, {0.401074, 0.436885, 15.0451}, {-7.33434, -11.0017, 19.4259}, {-6.85204, -1.80913, 31.0188}, {-2.24681, -3.44669,14.9831}, {6.88808, 12.5021, 12.2613}, {-7.17746, -0.544312, 32.7429}, {1.18296, 2.62785, 20.049}, {0.980749, 1.7896, 9.80252}, {-12.6072, -13.1204, 31.8528}, {-2.95474, -2.70339, 21.0908}, 
{-7.89887, -13.3905, 15.6659}, {13.8386, 22.0212, 23.5461}, 
{-3.30648, -2.41448, 22.7537}, {-7.64249, -12.7647, 16.0215}, 
{-12.5802, -21.1973, 19.9994}, {3.53783, 2.36905, 23.4593}, {7.75139, 12.7955, 16.5069}, {16.2947, 16.3433, 37.786}, {-1.83543, -1.13049, 20.9162}, {2.21734, 3.93892, 11.6063}, {-14.2372, -14.452, 34.5041}, {-2.64334, 2.64955, 28.4868}, {-0.0180721, -0.158769, 14.0396},{5.20997, 7.40744, 21.9042}, {9.9285, 6.41058, 32.6066}, {5.97198, 8.42471, 19.3019}, {9.143, 3.90521, 33.3541}, {3.09878, 4.52688, 16.4696}, {8.73578, 15.4112, 14.6941}, {-5.7819, 0.278884, 31.1284},{1.5669, 3.48784, 21.5614}, {509.742, 222.122, -7.08067}, {4203.77, 1316.13, -326.876}, {14395.5, 3962.48, -1444.29}, {34396.9, 8838.12, -3865.8}, {67519.7, 16620., -8097.86}, {117076., 27985.2, -14646.9}, 
{186377., 43610.5, -24019.5}, {278736., 64173., -36722.1}, {397464., 90349.5, -53261.}, {545872., 122817., -74142.9}, {727273., 162253., -99874.1}, {944979., 209334., -130961.}, {1.2023*10^6, 264736.,-167910.}, {1.50255*10^6, 329138., -211229.}, {1.84904*10^6, 403215., -261422.}
```

If I am evaluating the value of $f$ for each value of (x,y,z) given in above data set  , I am not getting the same parabolic surface.

```
H1 = Evaluate[{y^2/2 + z^2/2 - 16.7 z}] /. {x -> data[[All, 1]], y -> data[[All, 2]], z -> data[[All, 3]]}
```

I do not know where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Your data points are not on the surface -(x^2/2) + 16.7 z == 0.